# Как работает вынос видео в окно в опере

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть такая штука в опере, вынос видео в окно, которое стоит поверх всех остальных. Как можно реализовать подобную фичу средствами js?

Comment: поверх остальных окон системы? Или поверх самой же оперы и всех ее вкладок?

Comment: @alexoander, поверх все окон системы, но так чтобы работа с остальными окнами не блокировалас

Comment: ну это тогда уж ТОЧНО выше сил js - это вам к Win32 API и все такое